# Regular expression of the strings over {1,0} where all 11 occur before all 00

Tags: regular-expressions

I need to find a regular expression of the strings over {1,0} where all 11 occur before all 00.

I found the case where there is no 00's and where a 11 has to occur before a 00.

But I can't figure out how to make all 11's occur before all 00's

Answer (score 2):

This works:

$$1^{*}(011^{*})^{*}(00^{*}1)^{*}0^{*}$$

Comment: Wow, it looks as if you had already made my answer, then minimized it :-) It would be nice to read, how could you do it in a single bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The regexp is the concatenation of two sub-regexps:

1. The first part has no `00`.
2. The second has no `11`.

To generate the first part, i.e. the regexp of the language without consecuting zeros, we can consider: this language has at least one long of series of `1`s, separated with zeros:

$$(0+\epsilon)((11^\star)0)^\star(\epsilon+11^\star)$$

In human language:

- we start with a `0` or with an empty string
- then we have at least 1 long list of `1`s, suffixed with a single zero, 0 to infinite times
- finally we may stop with yet another at least 1 long list of `1`s.

For the second part, the double `1`-less language, we do the same, the result is

$$(1+\epsilon)((00^\star)1)^\star(\epsilon+00^\star)$$

Thus, the formula is

$$(0+\epsilon)((11^\star)0)^\star(\epsilon+11^\star)(1+\epsilon)((00^\star)1)^\star(\epsilon+00^\star)$$

Of course we could minimize it by converting it to a finite automata, then minimizing this automata, and then generate its regexp.