# Finding minimal DFA for language

Tags: automata

Find minimal DKA for language of all words in alphabet $ \left\{ 0,1 \right\}^* $ in which every double zero $00$ comes before every double one $11$. Also find the regular expression for the language. $$$$
I tried constructing a NFA epsilon, but I am not sure if my logic is correct.[image]

Comment: Find the regular expression for the language: see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3443173/regular-expression-of-the-strings-over-1-0-where-all-11-occur-before-all-00).

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression $1^*(011^*)^*(00^*1)^*0^*$
was proposed by Ekesh Kumar in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3443196).
Here is its minimal automaton:

$\hskip 20pt$[image]